# Audio Programming using SDL2 - Setting Up Audio Device

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm writing an old-school game engine in C and SDL2. I'm designing the audio portion now. Instead of playing .wav samples and the like for sound, I want to implement a sound generator, kind of like a SID chip in software (if you're familiar with the Commodore 64).

Here is my initialization code for setting up the sound device:

```
void initialize_audio(void) {

    SDL_AudioSpec want, have;

    SDL_memset(&want, 0, sizeof(want)); //initializes the 'want' struct
    want.freq = 44100;
    want.format = AUDIO_U8;  // 8-bit sound
    want.channels = 1; // 1 = mono, 2 = stereo
    want.samples = 2048; // how to decide on this? must be power of 2
    want.callback = my_callback_function; 
    
    // capture global audio_device_id here
    audio_device_id = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(
            NULL, // choose best device based on 'want' struct
            0, // want a playback device, not a recording device
            &want, 
            &have, 
            SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_FORMAT_CHANGE);
}
```

My question is (or what I need help with): I'm not sure what to ask for in terms of the buffer size in the audio device (the 'samples' parameter). I know this will effect how often SDL calls my callback function to feed more audio data into the sound device's buffer.

My guess is to keep it as small as a number as I can afford to do. The smaller the number here, the more frequently the callback function gets called, but I'm not sure what benefit this would give me.

Comment: If your callback gets called more frequently then it gets to react to changes faster - if you're playing through a callback and the player shoots a monster, then you can't play the monster explode sound until the next callback.

Comment: Ok that makes sense (Smaller samples buffer makes it so the game can change sound effects more quickly). My current engine runs at about 30 FPS. My sound engine component will only be capable of producing basic waveforms like sine waves and square waves. So maybe if I’m shooting for a sampling rate of 44100 samples per second, a buffer of 1470 bytes would be good. That would allow precision close to the frame rate. It has to be a power of 2 so maybe 1024 Bytes is the best choice?